# TFS 2015 has 8 collections need to migrated to Azure devops

Tags: azure, team-foundation-server, azure-devops

We have a 2015 TFS server with 8 collections to be migrated to Azure devops.

I have tried Microsoft Azure devops migration tool but it is considering each collection as single organization but we want to all 8 collections under one organization.  Each collection has different projects.

Is there any way to do this? I have seen Microsoft documentation but unable to get a perfect solution.  What should I do? could someone please guide me regarding this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the migration tool to move multiple collections to a single organisation. The migration tool is set to have 1 collection = 1 organisation.

If you need to achieve this under a single organisation then you would need to create new projects on your Azure DevOps environment, and then migrate the individual items from your TFS collections over (Work Items, Repos etc.)

Comment: Thanks Sam is there any tool to do migration of work tems and repos?

Comment: Repos are fairly straightforward, Azure DevOps has a repo import functionality. For work items here is an example of a tool that can do it - https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/